# Does Xcode use GPS points in a GPX file as per one point per second?

Tags: xcode, gps, gpx

I am looking into some GPX files and it seems that to simulate a speed, two methods can be used:

1. We can specify the location and the time:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode">
    
        <wpt lat="37.80902483738137" lon="-122.41545511468102">
            <name>Somewhere1</name>
    
            <time>2020-11-12T21:39:11Z</time>
        </wpt>
    
        <wpt lat="37.809034837381375" lon="-122.41544511468102">
            <name>Somewhere2</name>
    
            <time>2020-11-12T21:39:23Z</time>
        </wpt>
    
    </gpx>
```

I found that one other way is to not specify a time, and I see a file with many location, without any time this time, and separated roughly by `3.11365e-05` (using Pythagoras theorem). Xcode would seem to travel each location at a certain interval, which I am not sure if it is one second, and if I use 1.11km = 0.01 using the GPS latittude and longitude, then

```
3.11365e-05 * 1.11 / 0.01 * 60 * 60 = 12.442 km / hour
```

I can't find any official documentation about GPX locations being used with an interval of one second each. Is this how it works?